# How to initialize an array in a structure

Tags: vb.net, arrays, initialization

I am trying to initialize an array and assign values, but I am having problems

```
Public Structure test1
    <VBFixedArray(6)> Dim Id() As String
    Public Sub initialize()
        ReDim Id(6)
    End Sub
End Structure

Dim myvalues() as test1
...
ReDim myvalues(10)
```

I am trying to accomplish this with the following

```
For i as short = 0 to 10
    myvalues(i).Id(1) = "V"
    myvalues(i).Id(2) = "H"
    ...
    myvalues(i).Id(6) = "J"
next i
```

This is not working though and I am not sure of the proper implementation?

EDIT:

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Module Module1
Structure test1
    <VBFixedArray(6)> Dim Id() As String
    Public Sub initialize()
        ReDim Id(6)
        For im As Integer = 0 To 6
            Id(im) = ""
        Next im
    End Sub
End Structure
Sub Main()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim myvalues() As test1
    ReDim myvalues(10)
    For Each oTest As test1 In myvalues
        ' Initialize the structure 
        ReDim myvalues(10)
        oTest.initialize()
        ' Now loop through the array based on the bounds it was configured for
        'initialize to empty string(NOT ABLE TO ASSIGN TO> myvalues(i).Id(j))
        'I Get ERROR>>>Object reference not set to an instance of an object<<<<<
        'For i = 0 To 10
        For j As Integer = oTest.Id.GetLowerBound(0) To oTest.Id.GetUpperBound(0)
            ' Set the values in a case statement so that alterations to the size of the index won't break your code.
            Select Case j
                Case 0
                    oTest.Id(j) = "A"
                    myvalues(i).Id(j) = "A"
                Case 1
                    oTest.Id(j) = "B"
                    'myvalues(i).Id(j) = "B"
                Case 2
                    oTest.Id(j) = "C"
                    'myvalues(i).Id(j) = "C"
                Case 3
                    oTest.Id(j) = "D"
                    'myvalues(i).Id(j) = "D"
                Case 4
                    oTest.Id(j) = "E"
                    'myvalues(i).Id(j) = "E"
                Case 5
                    oTest.Id(j) = "F"
                    'myvalues(i).Id(j) = "F"
                Case 6
                    oTest.Id(j) = "G"
                    'myvalues(i).Id(j) = "G"
            End Select
        Next j
        'Next i
    Next 'oTest
        'assign<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< NOT WORKING>>>>
        '<<Id() is not set to <empty string> it is "Nothing"  I GET ERROR (91) next line and after
        'What am I doing wrong?
        For i = 0 To 10
        Console.WriteLine(myvalues(i).Id(0), myvalues(i).Id(1), myvalues(i).Id(2), myvalues(i).Id(3), myvalues(i).Id(4), myvalues(i).Id(5), myvalues(i).Id(6))
    Next i
End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: Wow! the famous `For-Case` pattern. Classic WTF - http://thedailywtf.com/articles/The_FOR-CASE_paradigm and http://thedailywtf.com/articles/Switched_on_Loops

Comment: Is this `VBA` code trying to live within `VB.NET`? There is no need for `ReDim` statments, nor `Sub initialize`. That is what dynamic arrays and constructors are for.

Answer (score 0):

The primary issue is that you are not calling initialize on the structure. You should change your loop to something like:

```
    Dim myvalues() As test1
    ReDim myvalues(10)

    For nI As Integer = myvalues.GetLowerBound(0) To myvalues.GetUpperBound(0)
        With myvalues(nI)
            .initialize()
            For j As Integer = .Id.GetLowerBound(0) To .Id.GetUpperBound(0)
                ' Set the values in a case statement so that alterations to the size of the index won't break your code.
                Select Case j
                    Case 0
                        .Id(j) = "A"
                    Case 1
                        .Id(j) = "B"
                    Case 2
                        .Id(j) = "C"
                    Case 3
                        .Id(j) = "D"
                    Case 4
                        .Id(j) = "E"
                    Case 5
                        .Id(j) = "F"
                    Case 6
                        .Id(j) = "G"
                End Select
            Next
        End With
    Next

    For nI As Integer = myvalues.GetLowerBound(0) To myvalues.GetUpperBound(0)
        With myvalues(nI)
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6}", .Id(0), .Id(1), .Id(2), .Id(3), .Id(4), .Id(5), .Id(6)))
        End With
    Next
```

Note that the bounds of the structures array are used to control the loop in case the size changes. This means that you will only have to change the size of the array in one location (the structure).

Also note that the values are assigned in a case statement. This prevents runtime errors should the array dimensions change. You will potentially have logic errors if you are not setting the right values, but these can be caught by a good unit test.

**Additional information**

My initial answer contained a `For Each` statement that iterated over `myvalues`. Apparently, however, this is not a valid operation against an array of structures: the element that you get in the `For Each` variable is not actually updated in the array. It appears to be a different reference.

I have never worked with structures in VB.Net unless I am using them to make calls to external DLLs, so this behavior surprised me. Unless you absolutely must use a structure, I would strongly advise changing the implementation to a `Class`.

Here is the implementation using a Class:

```
Public Class test1
    Public Id() As String

    ' Note that we can perform the initialization in the constructor instead of having to call a separate method
    Public Sub New()
        ReDim Id(6)
    End Sub
End Class

    Dim myvalues(10) As test1

    For nI As Integer = myvalues.GetLowerBound(0) To myvalues.GetUpperBound(0)
        ' Create a new instance of the class and assign it to the array element
        myvalues(nI) = New test1
        With myvalues(nI)
            For j As Integer = .Id.GetLowerBound(0) To .Id.GetUpperBound(0)
                ' Set the values in a case statement so that alterations to the size of the index won't break your code.
                Select Case j
                    Case 0
                        .Id(j) = "A"
                    Case 1
                        .Id(j) = "B"
                    Case 2
                        .Id(j) = "C"
                    Case 3
                        .Id(j) = "D"
                    Case 4
                        .Id(j) = "E"
                    Case 5
                        .Id(j) = "F"
                    Case 6
                        .Id(j) = "G"
                End Select
            Next
        End With
    Next

    ' Now we can use a for each
    For Each oTest As test1 In myvalues
        With oTest
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6}", .Id(0), .Id(1), .Id(2), .Id(3), .Id(4), .Id(5), .Id(6)))
        End With
    Next
```

Comment: your solution worked, although I edited my implementation in my original post to reflect what I am actually trying to accomplish which is very similar to your implementation, but I am having problems getting it to work. I was hoping you might take another look and see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: It turns out that For Each doesn't work correctly with structures, which was news to me (I don't use) them. I have updated my answer with a version that I have verified work and added some additional information. Unless you absolutely need the structure for some reason, I would strongly advise changing it to a class. In either case, the revised answer will work.

Comment: Seriously, would you write this? The infamous for/switch anti-pattern.

Comment: Gosh, I didn't realize we were writing production code here. The OP asked a specific question using a specific example and I provided education and information on specific issues they were having, issues I saw in that code, and ideas for avoiding those issues. Without knowing the exact solution the OP was trying to solve, this is the best possible approach.

Answer (score 0):

There is one trick to do this

```
Public Structure Test1
    Private m_ID() As String

    Public Property ID(Index As Integer) As String
        Get
            If m_ID Is Nothing Then initArray()
            Return m_ID(Index)
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            If m_ID Is Nothing Then initArray()
            m_ID(Index) = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private Sub initArray()
        ReDim m_ID(6)
    End Sub
End Structure

Dim MyValues() As Test1
ReDim MyValues(10)
For i As Short = 0 To 10
    MyValues(i).ID(1) = "V"
    MyValues(i).ID(2) = "H"
    ....
    MyValues(i).ID(6) = "J"
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want, although it is not very clear from the post:

```
Option Infer On
Module Module1

    Structure test1
        Implements ICloneable

        Dim Id As String()
        Public Sub New(ByVal list As String())
            Id = New String(list.Length - 1) {}
            For im As Integer = 0 To Id.Length - 1
                Id(im) = list(im)
            Next im
        End Sub

        Public Sub New(ByVal other As test1)
            Me.New(other.Id)
        End Sub
        Public Function Clone() As Object Implements System.ICloneable.Clone
            Return New test1(Me)
        End Function
    End Structure

    Sub Main()
        Dim i As Integer, N As Integer = 10
        Dim myvalues = New test1(N) {}

        Dim ids = New String() {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"}
        Dim prototype = New test1(ids)

        For index As Integer = 0 To N
            myvalues(index) = New test1(prototype)
        Next

        For i = 0 To N
            Console.WriteLine(myvalues(i).Id(0), myvalues(i).Id(1), myvalues(i).Id(2), myvalues(i).Id(3), myvalues(i).Id(4), myvalues(i).Id(5), myvalues(i).Id(6))
        Next i
    End Sub

End Module
```